# How to block rejected messages I did not send?

Tags: unix, exim

In exim mainlog I see a lot of rejected messages I did not actually sent (they were send from spammers).

```
2014-02-20 23:42:47 H=a94-132-158-40.cpe.xxxxxxx.pt (zonhub) [94.132.xxx.xxx] F=<e97c4cbf9b@xxxxxxx.com> rejected RCPT <e97c4cbf9b@mydomain.lt>: Email blocked - see IP 94.132.xxx.xxx is UCEPROTECT-Level 1 listed. See http://www.uceprotect.net/rblcheck.php?ipr=94.132.xxx.xxx
```

1. May I block them somehow completely?
2. Is anyway to prevent these type of messages, that are sent prentending as sent from my domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the discussion after my answers.

1. If you implement BATV (Bounce Address Tag Verification), you can block them as they come in.  Most of these messages are likely to userids which don't exist on your system, and should be refused on that basis.
2. If you set and publish strong policies (SPF, DKIM, and DMARC), many servers will refuse the spam and you should see less of it in a few days.  (Some of the servers sending this "backscatter" spam, may stop sending based on these policies.)

I ran into this issue with a domain a few year ago.  My first step was to setup a restrictive [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) policy on the domain.  This cut the bounces down significantly very quickly.  Try adding a TXT record to the DNS for the domain containing `v=spf1 a mx -all`.  A policy like this will enable mail exchange servers to reject the mail as soon as the `MailFrom` command is issued.  (Some of the sending addresses were harvested by other spammers and it was years before email to them tapered off.)

There are two types of spam that show up as bounces to your domain.  A small portion is likely to be spam sent as faked bounce messages. This will likely be targeted to valid addresses in your domain.  It is also quite likely that the sending server will not have the correct DNS records to pass rDNS (reverse DNS) validation.

The rest is "backscatter" spam which results from organizations which accept mail before validating it.  The then bounce the messages after validation.  If the sender is faked and they send the bounce message, the message does not go back to the sending server.  If you determine that these messages are "backscatter" you may want to notify postmasters at the sending domains that they are generating "backscatter spam".  Some of them may fix their configuration.

You can use Bounce Address Tag Validation (BATV) to reject this backscatter spam.  However, you should wait a week or two after you start signing outgoing messages before you start rejecting unsigned bounces.  I have documented how to implement this in my article on [Signing Return Path Addresses with Exim.](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/signing-return-path-addresses-with-exim/)

You could also consider [Implementing DKIM](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/signing-return-path-addresses-with-exim/) to sign outgoing messages.  This is another way that recipients can verify messages sent from your domain.  Your public key will need to be added to your DNS records.

You can publish you SPF and DKIM policies using DMARC which is an upcoming method to verify senders.  Like SPF and DKIM, this is done by adding records to DNS.  It provides a mechanism for recipients to notify how well mail claiming to be from your domain complies with your polices.

All the above techniques work best if you have policies in place stating that all outgoing mail for your domain originates from your mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way (I can't think of one) to block the reject messages being received by your server I wouldn't recommend doing so. While obviously annoying they are the only way you know that a spammer out there somewhere is sending messages pretending to be from your domain. If you start seeing a large number of those then you can at least be aware, and prepared if any of those recipients contact you to complain.

Since the messages aren't (I hope at least!) coming from your server, there's nothing you can do to prevent them since you don't control the servers that they are actually being sent through. About the only thing you can do is ensure you have the relevant things in place, eg properly setup reverse dns, SPF records etc, to ensure messages coming from your domain, but not from your server, are rejected and therefore aren't received by those people they're being sent to.